# \ifnum and real number

Tags: macros, conditionals

I have an error when I take a non-integer value for may argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\marks#1{{%
\hskip20pt plus 1 fil (#1 mark\ifnum#1=1\else s\fi)
\parfillskip=0pt\par}}

\begin{document}

Your mark is: \marks{5}  % fine 
Your mark is: \marks{1}  % fine 
Your mark is: \marks{0.5}   % error !

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifnum` is only meant for integer numbers, not for floating points.

Answer (score 8):

Classic ways to do this would be to use `\ifdim`

```
\ifdim#1pt=1pt \else s\fi
```

or `\ifx`

```
\def\tempa{#1}\tempb{1}\ifx\tempa\tempb\else s\fi
```

Answer (score 5):

`\ifnum` can only be used for integer numbers in the range -2<sup>31</sup>-1 to 2<sup>31</sup>-1. Dimensions can be used for numbers with decimal point, also with limited range (`\maxdimen` = 16383.99999 pt) and precision (the smallest unit is 1 sp = 2<sup>-16</sup> pt).

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\def\marks#1{{%
\hskip20pt plus 1 fil (#1 mark\ifdim#1pt=1pt \else s\fi)
\parfillskip=0pt\par}}

\begin{document}

Your mark is: \marks{5}  % fine
Your mark is: \marks{1}  % fine
Your mark is: \marks{0.5}   % fine, now

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

`\ifnum` can't be used with floating point numbers, i.e. it is meant for integer values only.

There are some ways: Using a `\ifdim` by-pass (like in the answers by David Carlisle and Heiko Oberdiek) or the `expl3` style with `\fp_compare:nNnF` which checks for the floating point 'entity'

This is easily achieved and can be extended, if needed, for more complicate issues, i.e. adding/multiplying marks etc.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% expl3 direct access
\cs_new:Nn \check_marks:n{ 
  \fp_compare:nNnF {#1} = {1} {s}
}

% expl3 wrapper/importer macro that can be used outside of \ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\checkmarks}[1]{%
  \check_marks:n{#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\marks#1{{%
    \hskip20pt plus 1 fil (#1 mark\checkmarks{#1})
    \parfillskip=0pt\par}
}

\begin{document}

Your mark is: \marks{5}  % fine 
Your mark is: \marks{1}  % fine 
Your mark is: \marks{0.5}   % fine
Your mark is: \marks{1.4141362}  % fine 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you use `xparse` you coud use `NewDocumentCommand` ?

Comment: @Tarass: Well, I restricted to `\newcommand`

Comment: What does that mean ? For LaTeX reasons or personal ?

Comment: @Tarass: The switch to `expl3` is confusion enough ;-)

Comment: Why not the simpler `\fp_compare:nF {#1 = 1} {s}`?  The abundance of braces tends to confuse me.